# What's the best solution to display HTML Content combined with native Content on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I'm searching for a good solution on iOS to display HTML Content combined with native Content on iOS

For Example in my News App, the DetailView looks like:

- Header: Native UILabel
- Picture Gallery: Native ScrollView with Paging
- Content of the Article HTML (first Part); can include external embeds like Twitter, Facebook
- Native BannerView
- Content of the Article HTML (last Part) ; can include external embeds like Twitter, Facebook
- Related Articles, Native UIView

It becomes really complicated because I've to put a UIWebView within a Scrollview: Scrollable Content into Scrollable Content. The height of each Webview needs to be set manually.

What is the best solution to implement this? Are there alternatives? How other News Apps do this (Like NewsRepublic)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use tableview or collection view (as NewsRepublic does)
You will have cells for the type you want to display 
E.g:

Header: Native UILabel - Basic tableview cell

Picture Gallery: Native ScrollView with Paging - Tableview cell with page controller

Content of the Article HTML (first Part); UITableview cell with NSAttributed string (or webview)
and so on.

Note that having a UIWebView inside a cell negatively affects the scrolling performance, so I would use a library that creates an NSAttributedString from it, like [this](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)

Since ios 8 you can easily set up a tableview with dynamic cell heights using only auto layout and automatic dimension:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a seprate subviews view as per your requirement and than add them in `UICollectionView` & show that collection view on screen.
Divide your view into smaller `subViews` and than add them togather.

As per your question your subviews can be:

- Header View (contatins `UILabel`)
- Picture gallery (can use `UIScrollView` Or `UICollectionView`)
- `UIWebView`
- `UIview` for Banner

... and so on ...

Add above subviews in `UICollectionView` as cells.

Comment: But I always have to define the height of each CollectionView and so calculate the height of each WebView?

Comment: Yes, that's the only way around :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CollectionView or TableView.

Add Webview, Label & textField in Cell and set UserInteractionEnable NO.

Set dynamic height of All Cell As requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to display `HTML` content combined with native content  is to use  `RTLabel`.

RTLabel works like UILabel, but supports html-like markups for rich text display. It is based on Core Text, so it supports some of the stuff that Core Text supports.

You can get it from the following link.

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel